# Get the option value of the select tag on load in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Just as we get the value of a select tag in jquery using $(document).read(function(), do we have something similar in Angular JS?

I'm able to get the value after clicking on a DOM element for which I need to pass it as a parameter

```
    var countryId = $scope.countrySelected;
    alert("country id:"+countryId); 

    // Ajax call for listing States
    var statePromise = $http.get("ListData.php?method=state&countryid="+countryId);
    $scope.states = [];

    statePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        for(index in data) {
            if (data[index].id) {
                $scope.states.push({
                    id:data[index].id,
                    name:data[index].name                   
                });                 
            }
        }
        $scope.statelist = $scope.states;
    });
    statePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Loading countries failed!");
    });
```

### HTML

```
    <tr><td>Country</td><td><select class="country" ng-model="countrySelected">
                    <option ng-repeat="country in countrylist" value="{{country.id}}" ng-selected="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
```

But, when I use it on load, it gives undefined, as the whole page data is not yet loaded. How can we overcome here?

Cheers!

Comment: For an AngularJS application you should use the model value. (The `select` should be bound to a property in your scope (by means of `ngModel`), so accessing this property gives you the value of the `select`.)

Comment: Can you explain with the code?

Comment: Not, really, because I don't see any code :) If you provide a fiddle (or at least the necessary code) I can demonstrate.

Comment: Updated my code. Please check it.

Comment: I added an answer. Please check it (and accept it if appropriate) :)

Comment: Feel free to also upvote the answer if you really liked it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the whole code it is not easy to determine what might be wrong.
In any case, using `ngSelected` won't change the value of the model attached to the `select` element. You should set the value of the `countrySelected` property inside the scope.
(I also suggest you use the **[`ngOptions`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)** directive.)

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="countrySelected" 
        ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countryList">
</select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.countrySelected = $scope.countryList[0].id;
alert('Selected country ID: ' + $scope.countrySelected);
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/TXJE6/)**.